# Не вытаскивается картинка из assets android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-assets

Нужно вытащить определенную картинку из папки `assets`. В данной папке находятся 5 подпапок согласно 5 языкам (`en,ru...`). В каждой подпапке лежит одинаковое кол-во картинок в формете svg единственное отличие как можно догадаться в локализации наполнения. Не могу понять в чем проблема, но картинка стабильно не отображается в imageview. Брал вариант реализации [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645268/how-to-load-a-image-from-assets) и сделал в итоге так:

```
val lang: String? = if (Singleton.sp!!.getString("language", Locale.getDefault().language) == "uk") {
  "ua"
} else {
  Locale.getDefault().language
}


try {
  val ims = context!!.assets.open(lang + "/" + "some_image_name")
  val d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null)
  questionImg.setImageDrawable(d)
} catch (ex: IOException) {
  Log.i("m", ex.toString())
  return
}
```

Вероятнее всего (не факт) проблема в имени которое я передаю:

```
lang + "/" + "some_image_name"
```

Но как правильно передать имя подпапки я не очень понял. Либо проблема не в этом.

Comment: Посмотрите что в переменной `lang` - возможно не то, что вы ожидаете. Или можно разместить их в папках `drawable-XX` (где `XX` соответственно язык) и загружать их как обычно по `id`

Comment: @woesss, это первое что я сделал)) думал на счет drawable, но как-то не смог придумать что делать с одинаковыми картинками и разделением по директориям :(

Comment: А логи что говорят? Сравните путь, который задаёте вы и который копируется в студии по правому клику на картинке и нажатии `Copy Relative Path`

Comment: @woesss, нету там `Copy Relative Path` есть только `Copy`, `// path` и `// reference` что из этого вы имели в виду?

Comment: Тогда подозреваю, что сама папка `assets` не на месте - на ней есть значок как на папке `res`? В стандартном проекте она должна быть по пути `<Project>/app/src/main/assets`. Попробуйте создать через правый клик в модуле, `New->Folder->Asset Folder` - если появится, перетаскивайте туда свои картинки

Comment: да есть на ней значок такой же как и на папке `res` вот путь к ней `D:\Android\test_android\app\src\main\assets`, вроде на ваш похоже

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105088/discussion-between-woesss-and-andrew).